# Feathers service with multiple endpoints. Single service or multiple services?

Tags: feathersjs

I am in the process of mapping an existing API (ebay REST API) to a feathers service and am trying to reason the best way to design the service. The API has multiple endpoints, each with their own GET, POST, etc:

- /ebay/inventory/item
- /ebay/inventory/location
- /ebay/inventory/offer
- /ebay/account/paymentPolicy
- /ebay/account/returnPolicy
- /ebay/account/fulfillmentPolicy
- etc...

I would like to avoid having to create a service for each endpoint and wanted to know if its possible to have a single service, with CRUD for each endpoint. Something like below, each subdirectory would have get(), create(), etc for their corresponding endpoint:

- services

  - ebay

    - inventory

      - item
      - location
      - ...
    - account

      - ...

The feathers scaffolding creates the following, so it seems like all I would need to do is add additional app.use('/ebay/inventory/xxx'). to the base ebay service. Does this look like a good way to go about this? If so, how does one add multiple endpoints to a single service?

```
...

module.exports = function(){
  const app = this;

  // Initialize our service with any options it requires
  app.use('/ebay/inventory', new Service());

  // Get our initialize service to that we can bind hooks
  const ebayService = app.service('/ebay/inventory');

...

module.exports.Service = Service
```